# Unix help with files

Tags: unix, command, grep

I have two dat files that are created by script and stored in directory.. is there a way to find what is happening with the files after it is being created.. how can i find that out.. one more thing what command searches for particular word in all files in one directory i tried grep -r.. didnt work for me.. any other suggestion..

Comment: "is there a way to find what is happening with the files after it is being created" - that is an overly broad question.

Comment: copy it and use diff? I'm not sure what you want to find out.

Comment: even i am confused.. so i am thinking abt looking under each script that may have picked that file for some other purpose.. how can i search the whole script and look for that particular word in there in all those script.. right now no one knows what happens after those dat files are created

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the files using **[`inotifywait(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait)**.

> `inotifywait` efficiently waits for
>   changes to files
>
> It is suitable for waiting for changes
>   to files from shell scripts

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others, the first part of your question is too vague. Why not add some detail like 'I expected the file to change like XXXX', how do I confirm that?'

You wrote

> what command searches for particular word in all files in one directory

Just use plain grep, i.e.

```
cd myDataDir
grep 'searchTarget' *
```

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question:

```
find . | xargs grep word_to_search
```

It will list recursively all files from the current dir (.) . Then it gives them as input to grep.

For the first question: if you plained to constantly monitor the files changes, you may consider to use svn.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand your first question. But for your 2nd question, to search for word in files in directory,

Pure shell solution

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *
do
  while read -r line
  do
     case "$line" in
        *searchword*) echo "$file: $line";;
     esac
  done < "$file"
done
```

Using `grep`

```
grep -l "pattern" *
```

Using `awk`

```
awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME": "$0}' *
```